# Why are complex valued zero and pole not used in lead or lag compensation design?

Tags: filter, control-system, phase, compensation

Consider the compensation transfer function \$\frac{s+z}{s+p}\$ so that the inequalities \$0<z<p\$ and \$0<p<z\$ correspond to lead and lag compensation respectively. It can be seen that at very low or high frequencies, the lead and lag compensators correspond to the behaviors of high and low pass filters respectively.

If \$s=\omega j\$, then the complex plane positions of the numbers \$s+z\$ and \$s+p\$ will lie on the same vertical lie in the half plane corresponding to \$0<\omega\$.

1. If \$z<p\$, \$s+z\$ lies to the left of \$s+p\$, so that *the phase angle of \$\frac{s+z}{s+p}\$ corresponding to the lead compensation is positive*.
2. If \$p<z\$, \$s+p\$ lies to the left of \$s+z\$, so that *the phase angle of \$\frac{s+z}{s+p}\$ corresponding to the lead compensation is negative*.

Therefore, in general, *a lead compensator trades phase margin for gain margin* while *a lag compensator trades gain margin for phase margin*.

> Is it accurate to say that although complex valued zero \$z\$ and pole \$p\$ can, in general, be used in compensation design, but are assumed to be real valued to avoid the complexity in design (due to the simple geometric interpretation of the argument of the complex number ratio i.e. the phase)?

Comment: You cannot have a complex valued compensator because it will not be implementable in a real/physical system. But you could have two of those compensators in series with conjugated poles/zeros https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/428164/analog-implementation-of-imaginary-roots-in-a-transfer-function

Comment: @jDAQ thanks for the comment. I understand that complex valued pole-zero lead or lag compensation is infeasible for real-world applications because the coefficients of the Laplace transfer of the plant required to stabilize are real valued. (1/2)

Comment: @jDAQ  however, suppose that the 'control algorithm' is tasked to [drive a Fourier series to vanish](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05250) so that the 'plant' transfer function has imaginary coefficients. In this case, would the statements '*the lead and lag compensators correspond to the behaviors of high and low pass filters respectively*' and '*a lead compensator trades phase margin for gain margin while a lag compensator trades gain margin for phase margin*' be accurate? It is unclear if these interpretations with regards to the corresponding Bode plot hold in this case. (2/2)

Comment: @jDAQ [the answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/428187/244079) to the question you linked in your comment, explains that the transfer function \$s(s-j\omega_0)(s+j\omega_0)\$ is not real-world realizable since the Q factor blows up as a results of the poles being on the \$Im\$ axis. Please try to comment on whether implementing such a transfer function algorithmically (modeled as ODEs) would have an instability issue.